# Javascript function not rendering within form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a select dropdown menu with years.

I'm using a simple loop to generates all the years for the dropdown menu, see `dateYear()`.

If I place `{this.dateYear()}` outside of `{this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition)` it renders correctly however when I place it inside `{this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition)` it renders the select element however the years don't populate.

I'm not getting any errors in console either.

```
export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const profileCandidateCollection = props.profileCandidate;
    const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;

    this.state = {
      careerHistoryPositions: [{company: '', startDateYear: ''}],
    };
  }

  dateYear() {
    var yearDate = '';
    for (var i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1975; i--) {
      yearDate += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $('select').html('<option>Year</option>' + yearDate);
  }
}
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      {this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => (

        <div key={careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={careerHistoryPosition.company}
            onChange={this.handleCompanyNameChange(careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId)}
          />

          <select value={CareerHistoryFormPage.startDateYear} >
            {this.dateYear()}
          </select>

        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what happened to the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most elegant solution, however, it's how I got it working. The problem was jquery. Thanks to @nem035 for pointing that out.

```
export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const profileCandidateCollection = props.profileCandidate;
    const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;

    this.state = {
      careerHistoryPositions: [{company: '', startDateYear: ''}],
    };
  }

  getStartDateMonthSelect(careerHistoryPosition) {
    const monthRange = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
      monthRange.push(i);
    }
    return (
      <select value={careerHistoryPosition.startDateMonth} onChange={this.handleStartDateMonthChange(careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId)}>
        <option>Month</option>
        {monthRange.map(month => (
          <option key={month} value={month}>{moment().month(month).format('MMMM')}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      {this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => (

        <div key={careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={careerHistoryPosition.company}
            onChange={this.handleCompanyNameChange(careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId)}
          />

          {this.getStartDateMonthSelect(careerHistoryPosition)}

        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```